# How do I blink/control Macbook keyboard LEDs programmatically?

Tags: python, macos, keyboard, blink

Do you know how I can switch on/off (blink) Macbook keyboard led (caps lock,numlock) under Mac OS X (preferably Tiger)?

I've googled for this, but have got no results, so I am asking for help.

I would like to add this feature as notifications (eg. new message received on Adium, new mail received).

I would prefer applescript, python, but if it's impossible, any code would be just fine.

I will appreciate any kind of guidance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://googlemac.blogspot.com/2008/04/manipulating-keyboard-leds-through.html

Comment: @Rich:  The information you added was completely irrelevant to the question at hand.  If you wanted to give useful source, you should've given the actual source to the app.  The reason I didn't do so is that it's very large: http://osxbook.com/book/bonus/chapter10/kbdleds/download/keyboard_leds.c

Comment: @Kev,  Erm, the article was what I posted.  He just copied in the compile line and the example uses, which aren't helpful in the least.  And yes, I was being a bit 'harsh', but I find it disrespectful for someone to edit a post and add information that devalues it -- it reflects poorly on the poster

Comment: I agree with Cody, I really don't know what Rich was thinking there.

Comment: @cody: apologies - looks like the @Rich answer got deleted and I shoulda looked closer at who wrote this one. Comment removed. :)

Comment: thanks for reminding me of this article, I have completely forgotten about it, cheers!